# postgis: point returned in ST_LineLocatePoint not able to detect in ST_Contains

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

I am using `postgis`'s `ST_LineLocatePoint` to find out the closest point on a `LineString` to the given `Point`, and using `ST_LineInterpolatePoint` to extract a `Point` from the returned float number.

`ST_LineLocatePoint` Query:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_LineInterpolatePoint(foo.the_line,
         ST_LineLocatePoint(foo.the_line,
           ST_GeomFromText('POINT(12.962315 77.584841)')))) AS g
FROM (
  SELECT ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(12.96145 77.58408,12.96219 77.58447,12.96302 77.58489,
                          12.96316 77.58496,12.96348 77.58511)') AS the_line
) AS foo;
```

Output:

```
                    g                     
------------------------------------------
 POINT(12.9624389808159 77.5845959902924)
```

Which exactly lies on the `linestring` I have passed. Demonstration is displayed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2p3zekae/2/).

But when I check whether this `point` lies in the `linestring`  using `ST_Contains` it always return `false`, even though the point lies within.

ST_Contains Query:

```
SELECT ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(12.96145 77.58408,12.96219 77.58447,
         12.96302 77.58489, 12.96316 77.58496, 12.96348 77.58511)'),
           ST_GeomFromText('POINT(12.9624389808159 77.5845959902924)'));
```

Output

```
 st_contains 
-------------
 f
```

I am not getting where I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me in this.

```
Postgresql : 9.4
postgis : 2.1
```

reference: [ST_LineLocatePoint](http://ST_LineLocatePoint), [ST_Contains](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not getting where I am doing wrong.

I think you're doing good... I had the same issue some time ago... I used [ST_ClosestPoint](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_ClosestPoint.html) to locate point on linestring and then cut a linestring with this point, but I can't.

Following the documentation:

> ST_ClosestPoint — Returns the 2-dimensional point on g1 that is
>   closest to g2. This is the first point of the shortest line.

So I get situation where one function says - this point is on a line, and other functions says - ok, but I can't cut cause your point is not on a line... I was confused like you're now...

In my case resolution was to draw another line which will intersect first line 'exactly' in given point and after that first line was cutted...

After some research I found issue was about rounding of coordinates counted and writen. I explain it to myself that, according to the definitions line is infinitely thin and point is infinitely small (they do not have the area), so they can easily miss each other - but it's my reasoning and I'm not sure whether it is good.  I advice you to use st_intersects, but with very low st_buffer or ST_DWithin function also with very low distance.

To be sure that your point lies on a line it have to be a part of this line (e.g. LINESTRING(0 0, 5 5) points (0 0) and (5 5). Example with point(3 3) works because it's coordinates are counted without any roundings.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a really common question (most likely a duplicate, but I'm too lazy to find it.)

The issue is related to numerical precision, where the Point is not *exactly* on the LineString, but is within a very small distance of it. Sort of like how `SELECT sin(pi())` is not exactly zero.

Rather than using [DE-9IM spatial predicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM) (like Contains, or Covers, etc.) which normally expect exact noding, it is more robust to use distance-based techniques like ST_DWithin with a small distance threshold. For example:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(the_point, the_line),
  ST_Covers(the_point, the_line),
  ST_DWithin(the_point, the_line, 1e-10)
FROM (
  SELECT 'POINT(12.9624389808159 77.5845959902924)'::geometry AS the_point,
    'LINESTRING(12.96145 77.58408,12.96219 77.58447,12.96302 77.58489,12.96316 77.58496,12.96348 77.58511)'::geometry AS the_line
) AS foo;
-[ RECORD 1 ]----------------------
st_distance | 1.58882185807825e-014
st_covers   | f
st_dwithin  | t
```

Here you can see that ST_DWithin indicates that the point is within a very small distance of the line, so it effectively contains the point.

Answer (score 0):

`ST_Contains()` only returns `true` if the `geometry` to test lies within the supplied `geometry`. In your case the `point` has to lie **within** the `linestring` and this is always `false` since a `linestring` does not have an interior.

You should use the `ST_Covers()` function instead: `true` if no point of the `geometry` to test (your `point`) lies **outside** the supplied `geometry` (your `linestring`).

Comment: to not consider your " `linestring` doesn't have an interior so it always return false" statement, check following query that returns true with `linstring` and `point` as input.
`SELECT ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 5 5)'),ST_GeomFromText('POINT(3 3)'));`